# How to tell when heroku preboot is live

Tags: heroku

We're using herokus preboot lab to minimize downtime in our app, but it takes a few minutes for the new code to become live.  Usually that doesn't matter, but sometimes we'd like to know when the new code is actually live to verify our fixes.  Is there a way to tell if the new code is live besides just waiting for 10 minutes?